# How can the signed area be 0?

Tags: calculus, integration

How can the signed area be 0? For example if you have 3 on positive x side and 3 on the negative x side then you get the signed area of 0? How can area be 0?

Comment: What do you understand by "signed area"?

Comment: Depending on what you are interested in, you can take the absolute value on some part of the integral (?) that you are calculating.

Comment: As you said, this is the signed area. If one part of the curve is above the axis and another part below the axis, the sum can be zero. Let us take the simple case of $y=\sin(x)$ that we want to integrate : if we do it between $0$ and $\pi$, the area is $2$ and all the curve is above the axis. If we do it between $\pi$ and $2\pi$, the area is $-2$ and all the curve is below the axis. So, when you integrate between $0$ and $2\pi$, the signed area is $2-2=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpret the integral of a function as  "area" only if the function is positive.

Otherwise, you may interpret the result as the area under the positive part of the function minus the area above the negative part of the function.

(N.B. I'm guessing you are talking about integrals, but your post is not very clear)

Comment: Yep, it says integration in the tags.

Comment: @KostasSt7 cool. So is it clear now or do you have some doubts?

Comment: The thing is i still dont get it, how can area be 0, if its zero it doesnt exist. But i am  guessing that signed area differs in this case compared to normal area.

Comment: @KostasSt7 Let's say that you have a square, whose verticed are (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1). The integral on this square would return $1^2 = 1$, that is the area of the square. If you move the square $1/2$ toward the "bottom", then the integral would **not** return $1^2=1$ (which is the area of the square) but $0$, because is the difference between the area of the two rectangles (the one above the $x$ axis and the one below).

Comment: I think i got it. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the deep question by the OP is the following.

If one takes a set and compute its signed area and finds  $0$, so ok, it is $0$ for this particular set.

But if one takes a set such that its signed area is $0$ so how it is? how can one imagine it?

It is this second part which he ask an answer for.

To answer this question, one should answer the same question for any number  $L$. If the signed area of a set is the number $L \in \mathbb{R}$ so how is this set, how can one imagine it?

The answer is that the set of points between the $x$ axis and the graph of $f$ can be partitioned into some subsets say $U_1$, $U_2$, ... under the graph of $f$ and above the $x$ axis and some other subsets $D_1$, $D_2$, .... under the $x$ axis and above the graph such that $L$ equals the difference $$(sum \ of \ area\ of \ U_1 \ and \ U_2\  and \ ....) \ minus \ (sum \ of \ area\  of \ (D_1 \ and \ D_2 \ ....).$$
It is possible that each $U_i$ set is empty (or each $D_j$ is empty). This holds if $f$ is only greater than $0$ or is only smaller than $0$. And we accept that the area of an empty set is $0$.

If this is the way you consider the signed area, then $L=0$ is only a particular case!